# Submit Form with jQuery/Plupload

Tags: jquery, plupload

I'm trying to get a form using Plupload to submit the form fields after the files are uploaded. I got this working on a simple Plupload page I built, but I'm trying to do it with the page made at http://designmodo.com/create-upload-form/.

I've tried using #("orderform").submit(); in the Complete function but it doesn't submit the form. What am I doing wrong here? I also tried to get the HTML submit button to trigger a file upload but that didn't work either.

This is jQuery code that submits files:

```
uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function() {
  $('.upload-form').fadeOut('slow');
  //document.getElementById("orderform").submit();      
  $("orderform").submit();      
});
```

I have more complete code at https://jsfiddle.net/jcyprich/9wggu9qa/.

Ideally, I would like to submit the form with or without files using a submit button. The uploader will only submit when a file is selected.

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake:
use "#" before id name.

Try this::

```
    uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function() {
     $('.upload-form').fadeOut('slow');
     $("#orderform").submit();      
    });
```

Comment: Hi. That didn't work. I also tried document.getElementById("orderform").submit(); which didn't work.

Comment: Try to call submit function before fadeOut.